# Python using a value in a list in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an excel file with hurricane data. One column lists the year, another lists latitude and another lists longitude. I'm trying to read the excel file to only plot storms in certain years. I'm a bit of a novice with python but here's what I have and it's unfortunately not populating the latitudes and longitudes correctly.

I have a list of years I call 'year' which seems to be populating from the excel file correctly. Then I am trying to say if a value in year == 2012, then only include the latitudes and longitudes from that year in the list which would be row values i to i+1 (which I called n). In the rest of the code I go on to plot latitudes and longitudes. But I am only having the problem with being exclusive about the years I choose. When I explicitly state lists of latitudes and longitudes, my plot works perfectly.

What am I missing? Thank you so much!

```
year = sheet.col_values(2,1,1602)
for i in year:
 if year.count(i) == 2012:
    n = i + 1
    lons = sheet.col_values(7,i,n)
    lats = sheet.col_values(6,i,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "year" will be a collection of years and not the row numbers, so when you do

```
year.count(i)
```

you are basically counting how many times the year 'i' occurs in that list.
You should instead check

```
i == 2012
```